# how to solve all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions problem during apending to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load my cat images in images folder and put them in a Numpy array named 'imgs' by looping over all the images in the directory to makes  a dataset for my machine learning program
    tried to resize

```
length = 128 # pixels in length
width = 128# pixels in width
imgs = np.empty((0,width, length, 3)) #empty dummy array

    for filename in os.listdir('images'):
        if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
            img = Image.open(os.path.join('images',filename)).convert('RGB')
            img=img.resize((width, length), Image.NEAREST) 
            imgs = np.append(imgs, np.array(img), axis=0)
         print(imgs.shape)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't use np.append.  Collect arrays in a list and concatenate once at the end.

Comment: So will all `img` be the same 3d shape?  Sometimes people try to mix 3 channel and 1 channel images and have problems.  In any case if you have list of (width,length,3) images, then `np.stack` will neatly join them into a (n, width, length, 3) array.